# Pulling data from three tables; Attempting to list project number, project name, and hours worked for projects on which the employee is working

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

Granted this is from an assignment, and the instructions are not clear as to whether I should list an employee identifier, however I am assuming I should (unless someone has another interpretation?).

This is the code I currently have:

```
select e.ssn, p.pnumber, p.pname, count(hours) hours_worked
from works_on w
inner join project p on w.pno = p.pnumber
inner join employee e on w.essn = e.ssn
group by e.ssn, p.pnumber, p.pname
order by e.ssn, hours_worked desc;
```

I get a list showing all employees working on each project, but hours_worked is always 1. I'm attempting to count from the hours column in the works_on table but it does not appear to work.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need  sum

```
select e.ssn, p.pnumber, p.pname, sum(hours) hours_worked
from works_on w
inner join project p on w.pno = p.pnumber
inner join employee e on w.essn = e.ssn
group by e.ssn, p.pnumber, p.pname
order by e.ssn, hours_worked desc;
```

count is for get the number of not null occurrence of values contained in the column

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb hahaha thank you so much! Been stuck on this for like two days - absolutely made my day. Thank you again!